# Download PDF from Byte array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying below code but this is creating file but not showing content. I need your anyone help, What i am doing wrong.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    url: "/searchModel/createPDF",
    data:"my_param",
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',  
    beforeSend:function(){

    }, 
    success: function(html) {
        /* html value is [37,80,68,75 .........] */
        //var file = new Blob([html], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        //var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        //window.open(fileURL);

        var blob=new Blob([html],{type: 'application/pdf'});
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download="SearchedResults.pdf";
        link.click();

    }
 });
```

Response coming from server is in byte array [37,80,68,75 .........]

Please help me if data in bytes array how it would be convert in pdf.

Comment: FYI: `contentType: 'application/octet-stream'` is for the `Content-type` of the *request* payload.

Comment: you don't need ajax here .. just specify the url your anchor link .. you cannot download file through Ajax..

Comment: Is byte data is correct to show create pdf.If i change content-type then it would be work right.

Comment: This showing byte array in browser window

Comment: Okay no problems i have to convert byte array to render as pdf file then its fine and working

Comment: how do you do convert byte array to render as pdf

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use AJAX to download files. It doesn't make sense. You can send the AJAX request and fetch the file contents inside the success handler on the client, but for obvious security reasons you can't do much with it. You cannot save it on the client computer and there's no javascript API allowing you to prompt the user where to save it.

So to download files, don't use AJAX. Create an anchor pointing to your server side script that serves the file to be downloaded.

Sample :

```js
window.downloadfile = function(e){
  window.location = "/searchModel/createPDF?" +  "my_param";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="downloadfile()">download file</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Kishore. But i think i need this after that call i am showing light box after and sending it to mail.

Comment: Yes you people said correct does not mean while download PDF using AJAX.  ** window.location = "/searchModel/createPDF?" +  "my_param";** is enough,Only we need to render pdf. It is default downloadable.Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you people said correct does not mean while download PDF using AJAX.

```
 window.location = "/searchModel/createPDF?" + "my_param";
```

is enough,Only we need to render pdf from server side. It is default downloadable.Thanks for your suggestions